# Convert V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV(YUV 4:2:2) to V4L2_PIX_FMT_YVU420(YUV 4:2:0)

Tags: c++, image-processing, yuv

I have been trying to convert YUYV raw file to YUV420 raw file in C++. The format are documented as in [YUV Formats Page](https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-old/yuv-formats.html). My output file shows a greenish look after conversion. I adopted the source code from [Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27638324/speed-up-yuv422-to-yuv420-software-conversion.html), to convert from YUYV instead of UYVY. Here is my source code:

```
void conv422to420(uint8_t* src, uint8_t* dst)
{
  uint8_t* pyFrame = dst;
  uint8_t* puFrame = pyFrame + width_*height_; // Cb
  uint8_t* pvFrame = puFrame + width_*height_/4; // Cr

  int uvOffset = width_ * 2 * sizeof(uint8_t);

  int i,j;

  for(i=0; i<height_-1; i++)
  {
    for(j=0; j<width_; j+=2)
    {
        auto evenRow = ((i&1) == 0);
        *pyFrame++ = *src++;
        ++src;
        uint16_t calc;
        if (evenRow)
        {
            calc = *src;
            calc += *(src + uvOffset);
            calc /= 2;
            *pvFrame++ = (uint8_t) calc;
        }
        *pyFrame++ = *src++;
        ++src;
        if (evenRow)
        {
            calc = *src;
            calc += *(src + uvOffset);
            calc /= 2;
            *puFrame++ = (uint8_t) calc;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

In general I took the average of the two U and two V values in two adjacent rows in YUYV to be the values in YUV420. I am just not sure if the "averaging it" is the right way to do this. Because I used

> ffmpeg -y -r 25.0 -f rawvideo -s 1280x720 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i yuyv422.yuv -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -r 25.0 -s 1280x720 -v debug yuv420p.yuv

to generate the YUV420 raw file successfully and the diff for my own output file is drastically different from the one ffmpeg generated in U and Y channels.

So my question is, are there any open source solution for such conversion？ And what is wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few trials of debugging, it turned out to be a small issue: I should have incremented src pointer after assigning U V values. Here is the code:

```
uint8_t* pyFrame = dst;
uint8_t* puFrame = pyFrame + width_*height_* sizeof(uint8_t); // Cb
uint8_t* pvFrame = puFrame + width_*height_* sizeof(uint8_t)/4; // Cr

int uvOffset = width_ * 2 * sizeof(uint8_t);

int i,j;

for(i=0; i<height_-1; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<width_; j+=2)
    {
        auto evenRow = ((i&1) == 0);
        *pyFrame++ = *src++;
        if (evenRow)
        {
            uint16_t calc = *src;
            calc += *(src + uvOffset);
            calc /= 2;
            *puFrame++ = *src;
        }
        ++src;
        *pyFrame++ = *src++;
        if (evenRow)
        {
            uint16_t calc = *src;
            calc += *(src + uvOffset);
            calc /= 2;
            *pvFrame++ = (uint8_t) calc;
        }
        ++src;
    }
}
```

Now I can see the images are properly converted. Still not sure if averaging it is the best practise. If anyone has the "best practise", please let me know.